# Reading in from System.in - Java

Tags: java, input, system.in

I am not sure how you are supposed to read in from system input from a Java file.

I want to be able to call `java myProg < file`

Where file is what I want to be read in as a string and given to myProg in the main method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the problem exactly?
1) you don't know how to start a java program with an argument
2) you don't know how to open a file within a java program which has the filename as an argument of the main method.
or 3) both

Comment: @Fortega neither of those. He wants to pipe a file in in lieu of system input.

Comment: @Peter sometimes reading 68 million pages is a little TOO much!

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you wanted to read from a file http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+read+in+from+file+example 754 million hits.

Comment: @glowcoder, You may be able to stop reading once you get the genral idea. ;)

Comment: Jarrod, this question was written four years before the question you've marked this a duplicate of...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use `System.in` to read from the standard input. It works just like entering it from a keyboard. The OS handles going from file to standard input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class MyProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Printing the file passed in:");
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to import java.util.Scanner

Comment: also, Scanner's documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 19):

Well, you may read `System.in` itself as it is a valid `InputStream`. Or also you can wrap it in a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Comment: Wrapping in a BufferedReader seems a bad idea because on Linux (perhaps not in every configuration) it leads to your program not getting the data after you type something in the terminal/PuTTy and press "Enter". In order for the program to get what you've typed, you need to send some special character to flush the stream.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, console input is accomplished by reading from **System.in**. To obtain a character based
stream that is attached to the console, wrap **System.in** in a **BufferedReader** object.
**BufferedReader** supports a buffered input stream. Its most commonly used constructor
is shown here:

```
BufferedReader(Reader inputReader)
```

Here, inputReader is the stream that is linked to the instance of **BufferedReader** that is being
created. **Reader** is an abstract class. One of its concrete subclasses is **InputStreamReader**,
which converts bytes to characters.

To obtain an **InputStreamReader** object that is linked to System.in, use the following constructor:

```
InputStreamReader(InputStream inputStream)
```

Because **System.in** refers to an object of type **InputStream**, it can be used for inputStream.
Putting it all together, the following line of code creates a **BufferedReader** that is connected
to the keyboard:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

After this statement executes, br is a character-based stream that is linked to the console
through System.in.

This is taken from the book `Java- The Complete Reference by Herbert Schildt`

Comment: excellent explanation!

Comment: Is clean up needed? Calling .close on the BufferedReader would call .close on the InputStreamReader, is that needed, or since System.in is not something that closes, we do not need to clean up?

Answer (score 5):

Use System.in, it is an InputStream which just serves this purpose

Answer (score 4):

You would read from `System.in` just like you would for keyboard input using, for example, [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) or [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can call `java myProg arg1 arg2 ...` :

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You probably looking for something like this.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("inputFile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: This is quite old post. Make sure that you are carefully commenting on something that is seen by soooo many people, thus, most likely many experts already checked it.

Answer (score -6):

```
class myFileReaderThatStarts with arguments
{

 class MissingArgumentException extends Exception{      
      MissingArgumentException(String s)
  {
     super(s);
  }

   }    
public static void main(String[] args) throws MissingArgumentException
{
//You can test args array for value 
if(args.length>0)
{
    // do something with args[0]
}
else
{
// default in a path 
// or 
   throw new MissingArgumentException("You need to start this program with a path");
}
}
```