# What is the use of System.in.read()?

Tags: java

What is the use of `System.in.read()` in java?
Please explain this.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

It reads a byte worth of data from the input stream.

Comment: see here http://www.coderanch.com/t/278751//java/system-read-method

Comment: simple it is used to get the input from the user. Google before asking here .

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid The concept (and real-world usages) of "standard input" can be pretty foreign to a Java programmer. While the `read` method is obviously explained in Javadoc, the intended use of `System.in` is not. Googling System.in does not reveal much, either.

Comment: Actually, I got here from Google.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

May be this example will help you.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int inChar;
        System.out.println("Enter a Character:");
        try {
            inChar = System.in.read();
            System.out.print("You entered ");
            System.out.println(inChar);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error reading from user");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't return correct values: for example when I enter 10 it returns 49.

Comment: That's because the ASCII value of '1' is 49. This would work as expected if `int inChar` was changed to `char inChar`.

Answer (score 49):

**Two and a half years late is better than never, right?**

`int System.in.read()` reads the next byte of data from the input stream.  But I am sure you already knew that, because it is trivial to look up.  So, what you are probably asking is:

- Why is it declared to return an `int` when the documentation says that it reads a `byte`?
- and why does it appear to return garbage? (I type `'9'`, but it returns `57`.)

**It returns an `int`** because besides all the possible values of a byte, it also needs to be able to return an extra value to indicate end-of-stream.  So, it has to return a type which can express more values than a `byte` can.

<sup>Note: They could have made it a `short`, but they opted for `int` instead, possibly as a tip of the hat of historical significance to C, whose `getc()` function also returns an `int`, but more importantly because `short` is a bit cumbersome to work with, (the language offers no means of specifying a `short` literal, so you have to specify an `int` literal and cast it to `short`,) plus on certain architectures `int` has better performance than `short`.</sup>

**It appears to return garbage** because when you view a character as an integer, what you are looking at is the ASCII<sup>(*)</sup> value of that character.  So, a `'9'` appears as `57`.  But if you cast that integer to a character, you get `'9'`, so all is well.

<sup>Think of it this way: if you typed the character `'9'` it is nonsensical to expect `System.in.read()` to return the number `9`, because then what number would you expect it to return if you had typed an `'a'`? Obviously, characters must be mapped to numbers.  ASCII<sup>(*)</sup> is a system of mapping characters to numbers.  And in this system, character `'9'` maps to number `57`, not number `9`.</sup>

(*) Not necessarily ASCII; it may be some other encoding, like UTF-16; but in the vast majority of encodings, and certainly in all popular encodings, the first 127 values are the same as ASCII. And this includes all english alphanumeric characters and popular symbols.

Comment: Not ASCII value; UTF-16 code unit. "9"->57. "[](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d400/index.htm)" -> [55349,  56320]

Comment: @TomBlodget I don't think it will return a UTF-16 code.  It views the input stream as a stream of bytes, so it will return a single byte.  If the stream happens to be a stream of (say, little endian) UTF-16 characters, then it will still be returning bytes, first the low byte of a UTF-16 character, then the high byte, then the low byte of the next character, and so on.  Of course, I may be wrong.  And I have not verified this.  But, are you sure?

Comment: You're right. The values are from the console's encoding. I'm just pointing out that the console's encoding is not likely to be ASCII.

Comment: @TomBlodget Oh, I see.  Of course.  I made a correction.  Please let me know if you still see an issue with it.

Answer (score 5):

`System` is a final class in `java.lang` package

code sample from the source code of api

```
public final class System {

   /**
     * The "standard" input stream. This stream is already
     * open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream
     * corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by
     * the host environment or user.
     */
    public final static InputStream in = nullInputStream();

}
```

`read()` is an abstract method of abstract class `InputStream`

```
 /**
     * Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
     * returned as an <code>int</code> in the range <code>0</code> to
     * <code>255</code>. If no byte is available because the end of the stream
     * has been reached, the value <code>-1</code> is returned. This method
     * blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected,
     * or an exception is thrown.
     *
     * <p> A subclass must provide an implementation of this method.
     *
     * @return     the next byte of data, or <code>-1</code> if the end of the
     *             stream is reached.
     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public abstract int read() throws IOException;
```

In short from the api:

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into
>   the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of
>   file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

from [InputStream.html#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29)

Answer (score 5):

```java
import java.io.IOException;

class ExamTest{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        int sn=System.in.read();
        System.out.println(sn);
    }
}
```

If you want get char input you have to cast like this: `char sn=(char) System.in.read()`

The value byte is returned as int in the range 0 to 255. However, unlike in other languages’ methods, `System.in.read()` reads only a byte at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement the accepted answer, you could also use `System.out.read()` like this:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException { // This works! No need to use try{// ...}catch(IOException ex){// ...}         

        System.out.println("Type a letter: ");
        char letter = (char) System.in.read();
        System.out.println("You typed the letter " + letter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18720909)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Really, this isn't any less of an answer than the accepted answer is, the problem is that the question isn't really a question.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Oh, sorry! I thought the purpose of this web site was to provide documentation for developers' questions. I was just giving an example that doesn't use a try/catch block.

Comment: Why "throws java.io.IOException " is needed?

Answer (score 2):

[`System.in.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) reads from the [standard input](http://www.linfo.org/standard_input.html).

The standard input can be used to get input from user in a console environment but, as such user interface has no editing facilities, the interactive use of standard input is restricted to courses that teach programming.

Most production use of standard input is in programs designed to work inside Unix command-line [pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29). In such programs the payload that the program is processing is coming from the standard input and the program's result gets written to the standard output. In that case the standard input is never written directly by the user, it is the redirected output of another program or the contents of a file.

A typical pipeline looks like this:

```
# list files and directories ordered by increasing size
du -s * | sort -n
```

[`sort`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort&ei=xiBEUf6gB8nMPcH9gYAK&usg=AFQjCNHmVN997nPl4AWwzIC4P_4fCswc9g) reads its data from the standard input, which is in fact the output of the [`du`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) command. The sorted data is written to the standard output of `sort`, which ends up on the console by default, and can be easily redirected to a file or to another command.

As such, the standard input is comparatively rarely used in Java.

Answer (score 1):

This example should help? Along with the comments, of course >:)

WARNING: MAN IS AN OVERUSED FREQUENT WORD IN THIS PARAGRAPH/POST

Overall I recommend using the `Scanner` class since you can input large sentences, I'm not entirely sure `System.in.read` has such aspects. If possible, please correct me.

```
public class InputApp {

// Don't worry, passing in args in the main method as one of the arguments isn't required MAN

    public static void main(String[] argumentalManWithAManDisorder){
        char inputManAger;

        System.out.println("Input Some Crap Man: ");
        try{
            // If you forget to cast char you will FAIL YOUR TASK MAN
            inputManAger = (char) System.in.read();
            System.out.print("You entererd " + inputManAger + " MAN");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ELEMENTARY SCHOOL MAN");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This... this is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to read from the standard input (mainly, the console). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java) may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

System.in.read() is a read input method for System.in class which is "Standard Input file" or 0 in conventional OS.

Answer (score 0):

system.in.read() method reads a byte and returns as an integer but if you enter a no between 1 to 9 ,it will return 48+ values because in ascii code table ,ascii values of 1-9 are 48-57 .
 hope , it will help.