# Get input from console in java

Tags: java

I used the following code segment to get 10 inputs from console in java and tried to print them for example in `*******12` format. In run-time, I entered 12,13,14,15 as inputs and then  the program terminated. Now there are 3 questions:

1. Why this code gets only 5 inputs instead 10?
2. Why this code prints for example 49,52,10 for input 14?
3. What's the solution?

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i <10 ;i++){
        try {
            int j= System.in.read();
            System.out.println("**********"+j);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and the output was:

```
12
**********49
**********50
**********10 13
**********49
**********51
**********10 14
**********49
**********52
**********10 15
**********49
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14 seconds)

Comment: What does `read()` do? You're using it, so I'll assume you've looked it up.

Comment: You might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446689/what-is-the-use-of-system-in-read-in-java

Comment: "Why this code gets only 5 inputs instead 10?".  Because you entered 10 bytes, which is what in.read() reads.

Comment: -1 for not reading the javadoc

Comment: Dear Franz I read the javadoc and I didn't find the answers. It's better to help me instead of giving -1. -1 does not solve my problem.

Comment: -1 isn't there to help you solve this. It's there to tell you that the community thinks you didn't put or show enough effort before asking the question. The javadoc says `Reads the next byte of data from the input stream.` You can look up what a byte and what an input stream are.

Comment: So I discovered that you don't want to solve a problem. You want to argue because you have lot of time!!! and I don't have. Please let others solve the problem and help me. bye

Comment: As members of the community, we try to improve the quality of StackOverflow. Some members have judged that your question is poor and have downvoted it. That's all.

Comment: The members must regards others. Maybe at that time I concentrated on one aspect of the problems and now you and others helped me to focus on the other aspects. So I tried to solve the problems and they solved!

Comment: I'm happy you got your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

49, 52, and 10 are the ASCII character codes for the characters you typed, <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You may continue to use `System.in.read()`, and process each character as it arrives. You would do something like the following:

- collect the characters that are typed
- look for digits typed followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- convert the ASCII codes of the digits to a decimal number

This is, of course, exactly what `Scanner.nextInt()` does for you.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: You can use a `Scanner` and `nextInt()` as suggested by other answers here.

Comment: I have added additional information about how you could get numeric input using only `System.in.read()`.

Comment: Oh Thanks. Your answers was really useful. Now I Know what's the problem and How Can I fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use a `Scanner` and the `nextInt()` method. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int j = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("**********" + j);
    }
}
```

Note that `read()` is a method of the `InputStream` class. You usually don't want to access an `InputStream` directly.

Comment: Yeah I know that class Scaner is another solution. But I need a solution using System.out.read(). So what's the problem in above code?

Comment: If you mean `System.in.read()`, there's not reason to. A Scanner is an easy and safe way to access an `InputStream`.

Comment: Meaning use it in inheritance because it's abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are running this outside of an IDE

```
String input = System.console().readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write one character and then press enter, it translates into 3 bytes: character_code + \r + \n. In your case it takes 3 iterations for i variable.

For 2 characters you type it translates into: character_code + character_code + \r + \n. It takes 4 iterations of i.

Btw, I have another output for the same code:

```
12           
**********49 
**********50 
**********13 
**********10 
13           
**********49 
**********51 
**********13 
**********10 
14           
**********49 
**********52
```

Comment: Thanks. You were helpful too. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should also help incase you want to use the bufferedReader

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        int inp = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
        System.out.println("----------- "+inp);
    }
```