# Why is an input compared with "-1"?

Tags: java, file-io, primitive-types

I was refreshing myself on I/O while I was going over the example code I saw something that confused me:

```
public class CopyBytes {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }
```

How can an int value (c), can be assigned to a byte of data from the input stream (in.read())? And what why does the while loop wait for it to not equal -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `(c = in.read())` will return `-1` when the end of input is reached  and hence the while loop will stop.

Read this awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34120618/1475228).

From Oracle docs:

> `public abstract int read()`
>                     throws IOException Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0
>   to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been
>   reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data
>   is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is
>   thrown. A subclass must provide an implementation of this method.
>
> **Returns:** the next byte of data, or `-1` if the end of the stream is
>   reached. *Throws: IOException - if an I/O error occurs.*

Comment: Agree, Mike Nakis’ answer is great for explaining this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [FileInputStream.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()):

> *public int read()
>            throws IOException*

Thus read() returns ints, not bytes, so it can be assigned to an `int` variable.
Note that ints can be implicitly converted to ints with no loss. Also from the docs:

> Returns:
>       the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

The loop check against -1 determines whether the end of file has been reached, and stops looping if so.