# Multi-Dimesional Array with User Input

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to change this code so I can get user input instead of a predefined array.  Can anyone help?  This code needs to have the method sum with the double[][] parameter. The method should return the sum of the elements of the array passed to it and should be rectangular.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Array2_1
{
    public static double sum (double[][] array)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++)
            {
                sum += array[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("")
        double a [][] = {
                {1.2, 2},
                {6, 7.2},
                {11, 12}
        };
        System.out.println(sum(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many questions about reading user input in Java. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446689/what-is-the-use-of-system-in-read).

Comment: Will the array always be 2x2, or should the user be able to choose the dimensions?

Comment: Copy the entire method, `sum()`, and give it a new name like `getUserInput()`.  Then change the `sum += array[i][j];` line so it gets a double from the user (see examples from the links provided by Bobulous). In `main()`, call your your new `getUserInput()` method, passing in the array, before calling `sum()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Scanner` to read values from the keyboard. First, read the values for the dimensions of the array and then input values for the individual indices using nested loops.

You can also define a method to display the array in the tabular form.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        int rows = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
        int cols = scanner.nextInt();

        double array[][] = new double[rows][cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("Enter value for array[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
                array[i][j] = scanner.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The array:");
        print(array);

        System.out.println("Sum of elements: " + sum(array));
    }

    public static double sum(double[][] array) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                sum += array[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void print(double[][] array) {
        for (double[] row : array) {
            for (double col : row) {
                System.out.print(col + "\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the number of rows: 3
Enter the number of columns: 2
Enter value for array[0][0]: 1.2
Enter value for array[0][1]: 2
Enter value for array[1][0]: 6
Enter value for array[1][1]: 7.2
Enter value for array[2][0]: 11
Enter value for array[2][1]: 12
The array:
1.2     2.0     
6.0     7.2     
11.0    12.0        
Sum of elements: 39.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments to the code for your understanding. Hope it answers your query.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //You can use the Scanner class for taking input
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //take input for the number of rows in array
    System.out.println("Enter no. of rows in array");
    int row = scan.nextInt();

    //take input for the number of columns in array
    System.out.println("Enter no. of columns in array");
    int col = scan.nextInt();

    //create an array with row and col as dimensions of the 2D array
    double[][] arr = new double[row][col];

    //this for loop is for inputting elements in your array
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            arr[i][j] = scan.nextInt();

    //this for loop is for printing out the elements 
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    scan.close();

    //now give a call to your sum() method and print the result
    System.out.println(sum(arr)); 
}
```