# Java System.in in an if else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, system.in

I want to be able to implement the System.in input into an if else statement, but have not quite found how, I'm a beginner with java and i'm creating a basic calculator.

```
//if input = fMultiply then multiply
    if () {
        answer = fnum * snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
    else {

    }
```

basically I just want the System.in between the if () brackets.

Comment: Store the result of the input into a variable, then use the variabke in your 'if'.

Comment: this question might help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in); 
if(Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()) == fMultiply)
    System.out.println(fnum * snum);
```