# input in Shell Script java

Tags: java, shell

I want take input from a file and shows the output to user using shell script java.

```
java programe < input.txt
```

I used the following command but it won't works.
Any Suggetions ??

Comment: are you looking for passing command line arguments ?

Comment: No I already used the following  "Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);" method
But for it won't works for taking and display inputs from a file in java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a newbie question, if you use google then also you could have got the answer.
Try creating a jar file of your java program and run it through a shell script by passing arguments from a file like,

get values from file using shell command amd grep,cut,awk etc.

```
val=`grep "expcted filter" file`
va2=`grep "expcted filter" file`

java -jar <your jar file>  $val1 $val2 > outputfile.txt
```

This will redirect output to a file which you can print through shell