# Dragon book compiler input

Tags: java, args

I'm executing the "Dragon book" front-end compiler, which expects a file input using

```
java main.Main < fileInput.txt
```

My question is: when I run args.length, the returned value is 0. Isn't fileInput.txt considered an argument? How could I catch it on code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not passing an argument to the program. Instead you are writing to standard input of the executed program (the content of `fileInput.txt` can be accessed via `System.in`).

Just in case, example reading:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

**Edit**: Found a similar question now, see: [Reading in from System.in - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, supplying standard input via redirection is a feature of the shell. The only way to detect use of this is using OS functions on the standard io file handles/descriptors.