# FileInputStream with System.in

Tags: java

I want to redirect stdin like this

```
java foo < test.txt
```

and read test.txt byte by byte in a function. I just want to do this:

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(System.in)
```

This should be incredibly simple but I've been pounding my head because I cannot figure out a way to grab test.txt without using args[x].

Edit: The issue is that I'm doing this:

```
FileInputStream readByte = new FileInputStream(file);
char c = (char)readByte.read();
```

It does not give the same thing as

```
char c = System.in.read();
```

Comment: Well, it's not a `FileInputStream` if it's coming from `System.in`, because `System.in` isn't a `File`.

Comment: System.in is already an InputStream. You can read bytes from it directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading in from System.in - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java)

Comment: I know but for some reason System.in.read() does not give me the same bytes as FileInputStream.readByte()

Comment: Did you read the documentation? One reads a byte, the other reads a char.

Comment: Sorry I was casting the byte as a char...

Comment: @shmosel Where does it say anything about chars? In the docs `System.in` is declared as just an `InputStream`, and `InputStream.read()` is documented as reading a byte, just like `FileInputStream.read()`...

Comment: @Siguza My bad, I was looking at `InputStreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for but check out this question:

[Reading in from System.in - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java)

They use the following method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Printing the file passed in:");
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: No, sorry if I was not specific enough, but the issue is that I'm doing this:

FileInputStream readByte = new FileInputStream(file);
char c = readByte.read();

It does not give the same thing as char c = System.in.read();

Comment: duplicate and repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java

Comment: @Akash I know, I already flagged the question. I also fully references their answer in mine. I only posted for OP's sake