# InputMismatchException is not working with Integer.parseInt( args [0]) ; than how can you get the exception to work, without a scanner

Tags: java

So if a user enters age as fishs instead of a integer a InputMismatchException prints "Error in the input enter a number".
or if the user does not enter anything in cmd (command line) than  a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException prints "Not enough arguments on the command line"

Fuuthermore   No scanner should be used. And  age = Integer.parseInt( args [0]) ; must be used to convert age from character to integer

Modify your program in Question to take the age of the user from the command line as the program runs. Your program should handle problems if the user does not input a number on the command line or makes an error in input.

Here is the code:

```
 public class age {

public static void main(String args[]){
    int age = 0;




     // try   
    try{
       // convert age from character to integer 
       age = Integer.parseInt( args [0]) ;

       // check input age value
       // if ueser inputs age less or equal to 12
        if(age<= 12)
        System.out.println("You are very young");
        // if user enters age larger than 12 and less than 20
         if(age > 12 && Age < 20)
            System.out.println("You are a teen");
        // if user enters age larger than 20
       if (age > 20)
            System.out.println("wow" +Age+" is very old");
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
       System.out.println("Error in the input enter a number");
    }
 catch ( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception0) {System.out.println   ("Not enough arguments on the command line" ) ; }
  }   
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java
This is duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading in from System.in - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java)

Comment: When you want the first argument you should use `args[0]`. Also you have to execute the program like `java Age 42` when you want to pass the age 42 to the program.

Comment: @Wufo and @Piro: This is not a duplicate of the question [Reading in from System.in - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5488072/8097737). Since the question is to read the arguments and not from `System.in`.

Comment: @devpuh he is already reading age from args[2], clearly question needs better explanation in that case.

Comment: Please follow the Java Naming Conventions – variable names (other than marked `static final`) should always start with lowercase.

Comment: @bob Please try to describe what your program should do and what unexpected output you currently get. Also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i fixed the question up.

Comment: So if a user enters age as fishs instead of a integer a InputMismatchException prints "Error in the input enter a number".
or if the user does not enter anything in cmd (command line) than  a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException prints "Not enough arguments on the command line"

Futhermore   No scanner should be used. And  age = Integer.parseInt( args [0]) ; must be used to convert age from character to integer

Comment: InputMismatchException is not working with Integer.parseInt( args [0]) ; than how can you get the exception to work, without a scanner

Answer (score 0):

So you want to catch the exception that is thrown when the input is not a number. Since you are using `Integer.parseInt(String s)` the thrown excetion would be [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). (See the JavaDoc for [Integer.parseInt(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)))

**Note:** You should follow the [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

You code should look like:

```
public class Age {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int age = 0;

        try {
            // convert age from character to integer 
            age = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) ;
            // check input age value
            // if ueser inputs age less or equal to 12
            if(age <= 12)
                System.out.println("You are very young");
            // if user enters age larger than 12 and less than 20
            if(age > 12 && age < 20)
                System.out.println("You are a teen");
            // if user enters age larger than 20
            if (age > 20)
                System.out.println("wow " + age + " is very old");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Error in the input enter a number");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Not enough arguments on the command line" ); 
        }
    }
}
```

But this code still could behave unexpected when the user enters `20` since the program didn't output anything in this case. To fix this you should change

```
// if user enters age larger than 20
if (age > 20)
```

into

```
// if user enters age at least 20
if (age >= 20)
```